# Scalar in compactification in several dimension

Tags: string-theory, compactification

In sec-$8.4$ $($String theory vol $1$$)$ Polchinski states that

> With more than one compact dimension, the anti-symmetric tensor also has scalar components $B_{mn}$

I am not understanding why the scalar is identified to the element $B_{mn}$. The scalar should come from decomposing symmetric-traceless, trace part of metric of the coordinates which are compactified? Like the scalar $g_{25,25}$ when we did KK reduction of $g_{\mu\nu}$. Most probably I’m missing some part?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when I hear "the trace part" of a metric in $D$ dimensions, I think of $g_{\mu\nu} g^{\mu\nu}$ which is just a constant.

Polchinski is talking about tensors which have a scalar as one of their [restricted representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation). In other words, exactly what you were doing by choosing indices that point in a compact direction. The observation is that for a symmetric tensor in $D$ dimensions, you only need to compactify one dimension to get a scalar. This would be $g_{25, 25}$. On the other hand, you would need to compactify at least two dimensions to get a scalar from the $B$ field because it is anti-symmetric. That means $B_{25,25} = 0$. You need to be able to write something like $B_{24,25}$.